# Using Java FileReader (or something similar) with username and password possible?

Tags: java, passwords, filereader

I have searched for a long time, but found nothing.

I would like to read a file with Java from a specific UNC filename (\\\) and have to enter a user and a password. 
I do not want to use ftp or something on ssh (or better can't).

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
public static void readFile(File filename, URL fileURL, User userName, Password password){

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename, fileURL, userName, password);

   ... do something with the file ....
```

}

Is there a way to do this with Java?
Thanks for your help.

[Edit]
I would like to access a folder from a user in an other domain. So i have to submit the user and the password for this domain user.

Another case is to access the folder of an foreign user in unix systems. eg. my user ist located in /home/me and i want to access the
folder of /home/you so i need to submit the passwort from the user "you".

Comment: *Why* do you need to provide a password? What protocol are you using?

Comment: You can't read files from URLs *at all* with FileReader. Not a real question.

Comment: I would like to access a folder from a user in an other domain. So i have to submit the user and the password for this domain user.
 
Another case is to access the folder of an foreign user in unix systems. eg. my user ist located in /home/me and i want to access the
folder of /home/you so i need to submit the passwort from the user "you".

Comment: @LStrike That has no bearing on my comment. If you have a URL, you can't use FileReader. Period. Do you perhaps mean *UNC*?

Comment: Ok, UNC may be more precise; path looks like this: \\servername\folder\file.txt

Comment: In that case you need to remove all the URL usages from your code, but the answer to your question is 'no'.

Comment: hmm, that's not good. Any idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the case of the UNC-path, you can give the JCIFS. (http://jcifs.samba.org/) a try. Its a prue Java inplementation of the Windows networking protocoll (e.g. Windows fileshare/map network drive).

Answer (score 0):

One way out is:

1. Host a file on some http server like tomcat.
2. Use [Basic-Authentication](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html) to project the file access.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible for me. I can not decide, where the file is "hosted"!  See comment above.